# Table layout alignment using groupBy and ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs

here is something that I'm pulling my hair on. I'm trying to group items and align them base on the date. I also group and count them, hence v.length, to show how many items are sold.

**Note:** I'm also using [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) for the groupBy

```
app.js
$scope.data = [
       { name: burger, category: food, date: 2-3-2015 }, 
       { name: burger, category: food, date: 2-4-2015 },
       { name: sandwich, category: food, date: 2-3-2015 }, 
       { name: sandwich, category: food, date: 2-4-2015 },
       { name: snacks, category: food, date: 2-4-2015 }
       ]

index.html
...
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | groupBy: 'name'">
  <td>{{ key }}</td>
  <td ng-repeat="(k, v) in value | groupBy: 'date'">
  {{ v.length }}
  </td>
</tr>
...
```

So the **actual result** is:

```
   |  Item    |  2-3-2015  | 2-4-2015 |
   | burger   |     1      |     1    |
   | sandwich |     1      |     1    |
   | snacks   |     1      |          |
```

But the **expected result** should be:

```
   |  Item    |  2-3-2015  | 2-4-2015 |
   | burger   |     1      |     1    |
   | sandwich |     1      |     1    |
   | snacks   |            |     1    |
```

How can I do the **expected result**?

Comment: How about `<td ng-repeat="(k, v) in value | groupBy: '-date'">`

Comment: need to iterate this data to create the date/count columns first.

Comment: @Hackerman it just changed the key/ date to negative and still the layout is the same.

Comment: @charlietfl after some reflection base on your comment. I was able to have a solution. Instead of grouping them on the view I generated a date/column columns first before displaying them on the view. 

so I was able to make a json data as follows:
{ Name: burger, firstDateSold: 1, secondDateSold: 2 },